# How to add an Extension to Outlook 365 event using Microsoft.Graph?

Tags: c#, events, graph, outlook

I'm using Microsoft.Graph to create an Office365 calendar event. It works fine and I can create an event but I need to add a couple of extra string properties to an event, so I've created an extension for that. It compiles fine. But when I try to run it and create an event with added extension, it throws an error:

Code: RequestBodyRead
Message: The property 'extensionName' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Extension'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.

```
//Extension
var evExtCollPage = new EventExtensionsCollectionPage();
var dict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
dict.Add("eSmtTickeId", "123");
            dict.Add("siteId", "456");
var openExtension = new OpenTypeExtension
{
    ExtensionName = "com.TechApp.Extensions",
    AdditionalData = dict
};
evExtCollPage.Add(openExtension);


Event createdEvent = await graphClient.Me.Events.Request().AddAsync(new Event
{
    Subject = "Service appointment",
    Location = location,
    Attendees = attendees,
    Body = body,
    Start = startTime,
    End = endTime,
    Extensions = evExtCollPage
});
```

What is wrong with my extension? I've struggled with this for 3 days now.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the ODataType has worked for me:

```
var openExtension = new OpenTypeExtension
{
    ODataType = "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
    ExtensionName = "com.TechApp.Extensions",
    AdditionalData = dict
};
```